# com_content task not on the controller's method?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have this link right here which I got on the restore button from versions in article manager. I was wondering on what specific task was loadhistory, since I cannot find it on com_content/controllers/article.php :

/BDES3/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&task=article.loadhistory

Sorry if this seems noobish, I just want to know the flow in the article versioning of Article Manager wherein I am able to select a previous version of the article and then restore it to make it the current article in the edit form, as well as update the com_content table for the current restored article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the function loadhistory and it is a function of the JModelLegacy class. which was extended by the model article. Here is the hierarchy of inheritance:

article -> JModelAdmin -> JModelForm -> JModelLegacy.

But how was this called in the URL

index.php?option=com_content&task=article.loadhistory??

Comment: Typically an answer doesn't ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

For content versioning there is a separate component in joomla named as  **com_contenthistory**.

In this component, you will find this mentioned task (loadhistory) in history model.

Comment: __construct
canEdit
delete
getListQuery
getSha1Hash
getTable
keep
populateState

these are the functions in the history model, there's no loadhistory

Comment: @LawrenceBatuhan Check the files on the administrator side. administrator/components/com_contenthistory/views/history is probably one you want.